# Facebook login not firing with Facebook-App

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I'm using Facebook-SDK (6.0.0) with Unity3D and trying to login , **it's always falling back to WebView login** while having FacebookApp installed.

It only happens with iOS,no problems in Android.

I'm initializing with this code:

```
FB.Init(onInitComplete, m_facebookAppId);
```

And login with this other one:

```
FB.Login("email,public_profile,user_friends", onLogin);
```

Always showing webview like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way iOS apps are configured and communicate, to get the native dialog switchover on iOS you must use the "primary" App ID (the one listed under "*2) Select Facebook App Id to be compiled with this game*" in the Facebook settings panel).

Comment: I'm searching for what you are saying , but i don't see that in Unity Facebook Settings inspector. Are you using Facebook SDK 6.0? http://screencast.com/t/Iotzl1SwNl

Comment: That prompt only appears if you add more than one app ID. Since you only have one, why are you passing an override to FB.Init()? It will use the one you've specified by default.

Comment: i have tested this solution and it is not working. Did you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: just use old plugin it will be fine. For example now latest is 7.9.* so i used 7.5.* and it will work hopefully for u as well.